Как предоставить доступ к сторонней папке как к static (localhost:8080/content/** к примеру)? Spring
Моя структура проекта выглядит так:

папка content создается в той же папке что и проект.
Как мне обращаться к нему через localhost:8080/content/** ?
Искал в интернете и сделал класс StaticResourceConfig:
    @Configuration
    public class StaticResourceConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/content/**")
                    .addResourceLocations("file:" + AppConfig.getAbsolutePath() + "/")
                    .setCachePeriod(0);
        }
    }


AppConfig.getAbsolutePath() возвращает C:/develop/TrainingSite/TrainingSite/TrainingSite (папка проекта)
При обращении http://localhost:8080/content/1.jpg ничего не выводит (Страница с ошибкой Белой метки).
Что мне сделать чтобы к файлам в папке content можно было удобно обращаться?

Поместить её в папку resources, специально для этого и предназначенную

URL-адрес для файла в локальной системе выглядит так:
file:///<локальный адрес>
соответсвенно добавьте 3 слэша в URL
.addResourceLocations("file:///" + ...


пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
